# Only the edge of the image is being displayed on the circle

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, css-transitions

Hi I'm relatively new to coding HTML and CSS. I'm using bootstrap as a framework. I'm trying to display a circle image however the image displays, but only the corner of the image not the face which is in the middle of the image.
I'm not sure how to do this, as I change the height and width it doesn't solve the problem.

```css
   .hrCircles {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    background-image: url('../img/karlie.jpg');
   height: 120px;
   width: 120px;
   display:inline-block;
   margin-left: 20px;
   padding: 0;
   vertical-align:top;
   transition-duration: 1s;

   }
    .hrCircles:hover {
     margin-bottom: 40px;
      background-image: url(../img/karlie.jpg);
     height:140px;
     width:140px;

    }

   .top-buffer{

   padding-top: 200px;
   padding-bottom: 200px;
   }
   .img-responsive {
   max-width: calc(100%/3);
   display: inline-block;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Survival Guide - About</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  
  <!-- Add some custom css -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row no-gutter full-height">
   <div class="col-md-6 well-dark-box fill overlap-down">
    <h1 class="text-center text-color-white"><big>About</big></h1>
    <p class="text-center text-color-white text-size-large">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed consequat rutrum mauris, eget venenatis ipsum aliquet a. Vestibulum pulvinar ut dolor quis malesuada. Nulla quis magna sagittis, fermentum lacus vel, sollicitudin mi.  
    </p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="img/car1.jpg" width="100%" />
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row no-gutter full-height">
   
   <div class="col-md-6 overlap">
    <img src="img/car2.jpg" width="100%" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 well-light-box fill overlap-up">
    <div id="text-shape">
     <img src="img/wheel.png" width="50%" class="curve" />
     <p class="text-color-white text-size-large">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed consequat rutrum mauris, eget venenatis ipsum aliquet a. Vestibulum pulvinar ut dolor quis malesuada. Nulla quis magna sagittis, fermentum lacus vel, sollicitudin mi. Fusce pulvinar arcu est, faucibus suscipit justo venenatis in. Cras eu massa imperdiet, condimentum libero ac, aliquet nisl. 
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <section id = "fordContacts"> 
 <div class = "top-buffer">
 <h1 class = "text-center contactText"> CONTACT US </h1>
 <h2 class = "contactTextAbout text-center"> So you need to contact someone before you start, 
                           here's a list of beautiful faces you can contact : </h2>
 <div class = "container" id ="contactCircles">
  <div class="img-circle hrCircles center-block img-responsives"></div>
  <a  class ="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone hrIcons" href="tel: +4401268406121"> </a>
  <a  class ="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope hrIcons" href="mailto: hr@ford.com"> </a>
  <div class="img-circle hrCircles center-block img-responsives"></div>
  <a  class ="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone hrIcons" href="tel: +4401268406121"> </a>
  <a  class ="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope hrIcons" href="mailto: hr@ford.com"> </a>
  <div class="img-circle hrCircles center-block img-responsives"></div>
  <a  class ="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone hrIcons" href="tel: +4401268406121"> </a>
  <a  class ="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope hrIcons" href="mailto: hr@ford.com"> </a>
  <img class="img-circle hrCircles center-block img-responsives" src="img/taylorb&w.jpg">

  
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </section>
 </body>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what version of Bootstrap you use but Im using 3.3.5 and this works fine...

```
   <div class="container marketing">


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">

            <img class="img-circle" src="Img/cake.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
            <h2>Special Cakes</h2>
            <p class="text-justify">Buy now.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="cakes.html" role="button">Go &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

In case that your bootstrap version dont have this classes, just copy them from another bootstrap version,

Comment: Hi Francisco, i have checked my bootstrap files and they are all fine, i'm using 3.3.5 as well

Comment: Well then use the classes from my comment, you dont need more css with bootstrap styles you going to have your images in responsive circles and like you want.

Comment: I can't use the IMG tag as i'm using a CSS 3 animation that requires me to use the div tag

Comment: Then add the img-circle class from Boostrap.css to your css.

.img-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

Comment: And add the width & height to the img tag, this looks great  width="140" height="140"